# modifying one element modifies the whole column in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
x = raw_input("")
y = raw_input("")
a = []  
b = []
count = 1

for i in range(0, int(y)):
    b.append(count)
    count+=1

for i in range(0, int(x)):
    a.append(b)

for i in a:
    print ""
    for j in i:
        print j, 

a[1][1] = 0



for i in a:
    print ""
    for j in i:
        print j,
```

a has been created by appending  list "b" n time to it
Now when i modify a[1][1] the whole column that is a[0][1] - a[n][1] gets modified to that value

Can anyone explain why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you append `b`, you are appending the same list -- not copies of the list, but multiple references to the same object.  If you want each row to be a different list, you need to append a *new* list each time, by doing `a.append(b[:])`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because by appending `b`, you are creating pointers to the same objects. Instead, make a copy as follows:

```
for i in range(0, int(x)):
    a.append(b[:])
```

You can see it working as expected, [**here**](http://repl.it/SoL)